# `docker run ubuntu:14.04 /bin/echo` produces SELinux error on Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, docker, selinux

I'm trying to get the [very basic steps](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerizing/) of the docker installation running and I encounter this problem on Fedora 20:

```
$ sudo docker run ubuntu:14.04 /bin/echo
/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

At the same time the SELinux Alert Browser records two alerts:

- SELinux is preventing /bin/echo from read access on the lnk_file . (Apparently the file name is "".)
- SELinux is preventing /bin/echo from read access on the file . (Empty filename again.)

What am I doing wrong, or is this a bug?

```
$ sudo docker version
Client version: 1.0.0
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.2
Git commit (client): 63fe64c/1.0.0
Server version: 1.0.0
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.2
Git commit (server): 63fe64c/1.0.0

$ yum info docker-io
Name        : docker-io
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.0.0
Release     : 6.fc20

$ yum info selinux-policy
Name        : selinux-policy
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 3.12.1
Release     : 177.fc20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using btrfs as your filesystem you can't use --selinux-enabled docker (--selinux-enabled is on by default from the docker-io f20 package)

From RHEL7 docs [5.2. Secure Containers with SELinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Resource_Management_and_Linux_Containers_Guide/sec-Secure_Containers_with_SELinux.html) (note at the bottom) "Note that currently it is not possible to run containers with SELinux enabled on the B-tree file system (Btrfs)"

Is also mentioned in [Docker and SELinux by Daniel Walsh from Red Hat](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWGFqMuEHdw) at about 35min mark

A few tests of my own confirm this as well. Fails on btrfs but mounting a ext4 filesystem at /var/lib/docker, restarting docker and running

```
docker run ubuntu:14.04 /bin/echo foo
```

works without error.

Answer (score 1):

In this presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/d0cent/docker-rhel, on slide 13 you can see what you have to to to allow docker to run with SELinux on Fedora 20.

Basically get a policy from https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/selinux-policy.git/tree/docker.te?h=f20-contrib

In that policy:

```
seinfo -t -x | grep docker
sesearch -A -s docker_t
```

or just unpack docker.pp with `semodule_unpackage`

For more info, as slide suggests, `man docker_selinux`

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more background information? What do I do with the `docker.te` file from fedorahosted? What do you mean with "In that policy […]"? I have neither an `semodule_unpackage`, an `seinfo`, nor an `sesearch` executable in my path and no manpage for `docker_selinux`.

Comment: I certainly could, although let me ask you another question? Do you use/maintain SELinux or you just have default installation and would rather disable it than configure? All in all, here's a basic SELinux guide: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux.html, here's a very good video explaining what SELinux is and how to work with it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxjenQ31b70

Comment: Otherwise you could just switch SELinux into a non-enforcing mode by following stuff here: http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html#DIS2, but do consider what this website has to say: http://stopdisablingselinux.com/

Comment: I just have a default installation and would prefer not to disable SELinux. As far as I was concerned with SELinux up until now everything "just worked" with the default policies provided by Fedora. So is that not also the expected behavior for docker? Or is there some inherent complexity in the container approach that requires manual configuration of SELinux? Thanks for the video, I'll watch it as soon as I have the time.

Comment: Default SELinux is tailored for stuff that's really integrated into Fedora, I'd assume docker is a bit too fresh to make it into the mainstream. I'd love to tell you more on it, but I didn't use RedHat for a few years, don't have any docker experience on either RH or Fedora, sorry :( These manuals and videos, however, did help me back in the day in general understanding of SELinux and what to do with it. Bottomline, short answer: docker seems to not to be included in standard SELinux config.